# Is it possible to get an estimation on execution time of Dask operations

Tags: dask

I know its a very specific to the environment running the code but given dask calculates its execution plan in advance into a DAG is there a way to understand how long that execution should take?

The progress bar is a great help once execution is running but would it be possible to understand beforehand how long to expect a series of operations should take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short Answer

No.

#### Explanation

The Dask scheduler just executes Python functions.  It doesn't think about where they came from or the broader context of what they represent (for example, a dataframe join or matrix multiply).  From its perspective it has just been asked to execute a graph of opaque function calls.  This generality is a weakness (hard to perform high level analysis) but also Dask's main strength, because it can be applied to a broad variety of problems outside of any particular domain or specialty.

The distributed scheduler *does* maintain an exponentially weighted average of each function's duration which *could* be used to create an estimate of a task graph.  I would search the [scheduler.py](https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/master/distributed/scheduler.py) file for `task_duration` if you're interested in building this.